# How to write next to date in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, calendar, momentjs

I have a calendar in which I want an if case that allows me to get rid of the enddate if a single date booking is made:

```
if (Startdate next to Enddate); {
 Enddate = False 

}
```

How would I be able to phrase "next to" if Startdate and enddate are both already in their own arrays?

But have no idea how to format it.

Comment: Add 1 day to `StartDate`, and test if that's the same as `EndDate`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have separate arrays for Startdate and Enddate, you can use the following code to check if the dates are adjacent:

```
if (Startdate[index].getTime() === Enddate[index].getTime() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) {
  Enddate[index] = false;
}
```